# How to create a background in Blender?

Tags: modeling

I have spent ages creating a model, but along the way I must have accidentally clicked something because when I try to add lighting it doesn't work, or when I try to add a cloud background to my model, this doesn't show up either. I have attached pictures. Does anyone know why this might be? Thanks[image]

Comment: You need to connect your image texture through the background node before going into the output - the trick though, is that it shouldn't be an _Image Texture_ node, it should be an _Environment Texture_ node (you are using _image texture_ in the provided image).

Comment: please pack your image and share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @ChristopherBennett thank you so much for your help!